# Study endomorphism diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an endomorphism whose matrix is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1+a & -a & a \\ 
2+a & -a & a-1 \\ 
2 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

How can I study if it's diagonalizable or not depending of $a$? It's possible to calculate the characteristic polynomial, but it's a nightmare and I won't have enough time in an exam. Is there any "trick" or something?

Comment: I think it's not that nightmare to calculate the characteristic polynomial.
You may also consider the definition: Find a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$

Answer (score 2):

Astonishingly, the characteristic polynomial doesn't depend on $\;a\;$ :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1+a&-a&a\\
2+a&-a&a-1\\
2&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\implies p_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}t-1-a&a&-a\\
-2-a&t+a&-a+1\\
-2&1&t\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=(t-1)^2(t+1)$$

Thus, the matrix is diagonalizable iff the geometric multiplicity of $\;\lambda =1\;$ is two, so we form the corresponding homogeneous linear system to check this:

$$\lambda=1:\;\;\;\begin{align*}&-ax&+ay&-az&=0\\&-(a+2)x&+(a+1)y&-(a-1)z&=0\\&-2x&-y&+z&=0\end{align*}$$

The last equation above is the first one minus the second one, so we get the equivalent system

$$\begin{align*}I&\;\;\;&-ax&+ay&-az&=0\\II&\;\;\;&-2x&-y&+z&=0\end{align*}$$

and from here:

$$x\stackrel{II}=\frac12(z-y)\stackrel I\implies-\frac a2(z-y)+ay-az=0\implies$$

$$\left[3ax=\right]\frac32a\left(z-y\right)=0$$

Looking at the last equation and knowing $\;x\;$ depends linearly on $\;y,z\;$ , we see the above linear system has a solution space of dimension two iff $\;a=0\;$ , otherwise we're forced to $\;x=0\;,\;\;y=z\;$, which gives a solution space of dimension 1.